# why we use ref.current instead of just put the condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

can anyone tell me why we use if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) instead of if (!ref.current.contains(event.target))

```
function useOutsideAlerter(ref) {
  useEffect(() => {
 
    // Function for click event
    function handleOutsideClick(event) {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        alert("you just clicked outside of box!");
      }
    }
 
    // Adding click event listener
    document.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
  }, [ref]);
}
```

Comment: This suggests to me that `ref` might not always have a value for `ref.current` and your code is trying to handle those cases. Hard to say when or why that happens because we can't see the code that uses this function.

Comment: Because `ref.current` can be undefined or null and the next code would throw an error if so

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs)

> When a `ref` is passed to an element in render, a reference to the node becomes accessible at the `current` attribute of the ref.

`ref` itself might have a value, but to access the element you need to use `ref.current` which can be undefined.

To make your syntax shorter you can use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
if (!ref.current?.contains(event.target) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The property .current can be null, so e just have to safe guard that the property is Not null before trying to read the .current property. Remember .current is set after the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

So main issue is that ref may not be set on first render. It was guarantied to be set in componentDidMount, when we used classes for example, but in functional components it's a little bit more tricky, since we don't have such thing as lifecycles and we have an effects, so it's useful to check, if that ref value is set.

Answer (score 1):

because current can be undefined..but you can do `!ref.current?.contains()`.